# Customize equation numbering for Equation environment for Supplementary Material?

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I need a different numbering style for equations in the Supplementary Material, for example use

> (S.1)

instead of

> (1.1)

It works manually with `\tag{S.1}` but is there a way to change the style for the whole document to (1) keep numbering automatic, (2) be able to use automatic cross referencing between main text and supplementary text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\tag{S.1}
\bar\gamma_M:=\frac{1}{\alpha+\alpha'}, \quad  \bar\gamma_Z:=\frac{1}{\gamma+\gamma'}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Hope that's better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the definition of `\theequation` when the supplementary material starts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Main material}

We have an equation
\begin{equation}\label{main}
0=0
\end{equation}
that will be used in~\eqref{suppl}.

\section{Supplementary material}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S.\arabic{equation}}

This equation is clearer than~\eqref{main}
\begin{equation}\label{suppl}
\bar\gamma_M=\frac{1}{\alpha+\alpha'}, \quad  \bar\gamma_Z=\frac{1}{\gamma+\gamma'}.
\end{equation}
but more difficult.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you introduce the supplementary material with `\section*`, add also

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

after the `\renewcommand` line.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with `\newtagform` and `\usetagform`, from `mathtools`. However note tha cross referencing will have to be done by hand:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{supplementary}[S.]()
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq}
\bar\gamma_M:=\frac{1}{\alpha+\alpha'}, \quad \bar\gamma_Z:=\frac{1}{\gamma+\gamma'}.
\end{equation}

\section{Supplementary material}
\usetagform{supplementary}
\begin{equation} \label{eq-S}
\bar\gamma_M:=\frac{1}{\alpha+\alpha'}, \quad \bar\gamma_Z:=\frac{1}{\gamma+\gamma'}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it so that I'll be able to use the xr package for automatic cross referencing?

Comment: Also I get the error message "! Undefined control sequence. \couterwithin" when I compile your code. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you forget to type the first `n` from `\counterwithin`? Or is your LaTeX installation up-to-date?

Comment: For you first comment, I don't know, as I never used `xr`.

Comment: No I mistyped here sorry but I copied pasted your code.

Comment: Actually I get a warning but it still generates a pdf.

Comment: Which warning ?